Docker container fails after a warning "Use of eval in "node_modules/three-stdlib/libs/lottie.js" is strongly discouraged"
After trying to run a react-vite container with its corresponding image, it fails after receiving the following in the logs:

node_modules/three-stdlib/libs/lottie.js (13062:32): Use of eval in
"node_modules/three-stdlib/libs/lottie.js" is strongly discouraged as
it poses security risks and may cause issues with modification.

Once it finished the build, the container is down.
The Dockerfile:
FROM node:latest AS builder

WORKDIR /src

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]



I've tried finding additional discussions regarding this matter however I couldn't find any.
package.json:
{
  "name": "project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "start": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^4.3.3",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.105.4",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.16.2",
    "framer-motion": "^11.1.7",
    "maath": "^0.10.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-parallax-tilt": "^1.7.225",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.0",
    "react-social-icons": "^6.16.0",
    "react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.6.0",
    "three": "^0.164.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^16.1.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@rollup/rollup-linux-x64-gnu": "4.6.1"
  }
}

vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: { chunkSizeWarningLimit: 1600 },
  preview: {
    port: 3000,
    strictPort: true,
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    strictPort: true,
    host: true,
  },
});

As can be seen in the package.json file, the project uses 3d model files, framer motions etc.

The warning isn't wrong – eval in most languages typically is a major security issue – but there's not enough information in your question to say what might be causing this.  Beyond the routine Node Dockerfile, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Does the same program run on plain Node without Docker?

This is odd - I have noticed that the aforementioned repo states that there are emphasized files - although there are none. some of the packages were installed using legacy peer dependency which may have caused it -
I reproduced it with a new repo with the same files, dependencies and all but I have installed everything with no --legacy-peer-deps flags, seems to solve it for some reason although some of these packages shouldn't be compatible as far as I know.
